# How to set the default background/text color scheme in QtConsole for iPython?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ipython

I can set the color scheme of the initial tab in Qt Console by using the following command line:

```
ipython qtconsole --colors=linux
```

But each subsequent tab I open (Ctrl + T) in Qt Console defaults back to a white background and dark text. Is there any way to change the color scheme of new tabs too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in 0.12, and has been [fixed](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1363) in master.  So the only way to get what you want is to update to master, or wait for 0.13 (soonish).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I'll just wait.