# ipython qtconsole --colors=linux doesnt work

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, qtconsole

I launched qtconsole using: `ipython qtconsole --colors=linux` on my `windows 8.1` machine.

Yet the background colour is still eye retina burning white. So are all the tabs I open within.

I have the following versions installed:

```
Jupyter QtConsole 4.2.1
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

There is a link that describes something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407156/how-to-set-the-default-background-text-color-scheme-in-qtconsole-for-ipython) but I should have a later version.

Why does this not work for me?

Comment: are you sure that you don't need to run `jupyter qtconsole`?

Comment: exact same thing happens when I replace *ipython* with *jupyter*